# How to tell if a Fragment was recreated or retained

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a Fragment that has `setRetainInstance(true)`. In the parent Activity's `onCreate()`, I first check if the Fragment is already attached to the Activity using `FragmentManager.findFragmentById(id)` before instantiating and attaching a new Fragment.

For non-null values returned by `findFragmentById(id)`, is there any way to tell if the Fragment returned was recreated or retained from the previous Activity that was killed?

Comment: in oncreate if  findFragmentById(id) returns non null, means it was retained

Comment: @baboo, if the Fragment was recreated by the platform, findFragmentById would also return non-null.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/08/retain-fragment-instance-across.html